# How to link directly to Gmail's Spam Folder

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention

I'm trying to help our users find our confirmation email if it's in their spam folder.

So if they have an @gmail.com address I'll link to "how to search" and "look in your spam folder"

Answer (score 2):

I THINK it's this:  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#spam

Then you'll need to login.
Tested it while logged into gmail and then in an Incognito Chrome window (it prompted me to sign into Gmail. After signing in, I had to click the link again to get to the Spam Folder.

And of course, you can type : In:Spam  to get to the spam folder.

Comment: Didn't work for me on my Nexus 4, using the mobile website.

Comment: That link will work as long as the user is logged into just one Google account _or_ the first Google account they logged into is the one they want to use.